# Two polynomials with the same root

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

I have come across this problem many times. And quite often this has no proof attached with it. Is this an elementary concept I am missing and is there a way this can be visualised in Desmos?

$P(x) = x^4 + ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d $

$Q(x) = x^2 + px + q$

both have real coefficients.

If r and s are two roots of the these equations. Why does my book say that $P(x) - Q(x)$ also has roots r and s.

Moreover, the book also says that since P(x) - Q(x) is non-negative, r & s are double roots i.e.
$P(x) - Q(x) = (x-s)^2(x-r)^2$

Just out of curiosity, is there a way to find out P(x) with this information?

Comment: If $P(r)=0$ and $Q(r)=0$ then $P(r)-Q(r)=0$. But it doesn't follow from just what you wrote that $P(x)-Q(x)$ must be non-negative.

Comment: Yeah. Double roots are always confusing

Comment: consider $P(x)=(x-3)(x-4)(x-6)^2$,$Q(x)=(x-3)(x-4)$, then $P(x)-Q(x)\neq (x-3)^2(x-4)^2$,moreover,$P(6)-Q(6)<0$,there may be some correction in your book,or they may be a typo in your question please check

Comment: I'll check. Thanks.

Comment: If we know that $P-Q$ is non-negative, then we do have double roots.  At an odd-order root, the graph crosses the axis, like $x$ or $x^3$ at $0$.  I think there may be more assumptions in the book than you've told us.

Comment: @saulspatz Perhaps!

Comment: @saulspatz $x^4-x^2$ is non negative but doesn't have double roots

Comment: @LalitTolani $x^4-x^2$ is negative when $0<x<1$...it should be $x^4+x^2$?

Comment: yes I forgot that fractional numbers on raising to higher power decrease it should be as you told

Comment: @LalitTolani I think you are trying to construct a polynomial with no real roots, but that conflicts with the given data.

Comment: where did given data said that roots must be real

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to tell you

If some $P(x)$ has roots $ \alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$

And some $G(x)$ has roots $\alpha,\beta,\theta,\phi$

Then for some $k_1,k_2$ $ \epsilon$ $ R$ such that $k_1.k_2\neq0$

The roots of $k_1.P(x)\pm k_2.G(x)$ are $\alpha,\beta$

Your second claim appears to have some ambiguity as indicated in comments

As an reply to your comment, we have

$P(x)=a_1(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$

$G(x)=a_2(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\theta)(x-\phi)$

For a simple case consider $k_1=k_2=1$, hence

$P(x)\pm G(x)=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(a_1(x-\gamma)(x-\delta)-a_2(x-\theta)(x-\phi))$

Clearly Two roots( from first two brackets) will be $\alpha, \beta$ and the other two (from third bracket) will be different and will never be equal to either of $\gamma,\delta,\theta,\phi$

[image: Your desmos link]

Comment: Can you give a link to a graphical representation on Desmos or notes that elaborate this point?

Comment: Yes sure But please wait It will take a while to search for them

Comment: Thanks! Anytime will do.

Comment: please see edit for proof

Comment: I provided QR code for desmos page

Comment: Exactly what was needed. Thanks.

Comment: Happy to help you

Answer (score 1):

If r and s are two roots of the these equations.

That means P(s) = P(r) = 0 and Q(s) = Q(r) = 0

1. Why does my book say that P(x)−Q(x) also has roots r and s.

Let's say K(x) = P(x) - Q(x)

K(s) = P(s) - Q(s) = 0

K(r) = P(r) - Q(r) = 0

So, r and s are roots of K(x)

2. is there a way to find out P(x) with this information?

P(x) - Q(x) = (x-s)²(x-r)² = (x²-2xs+s²)(x²-2xr+r²)

= x⁴ - 2x³r + x²r² - 2x³s + 4x²rs -2xsr² + x²s²  -2xrs² + r²s²

P(x) =  x⁴ - 2x³r + x²r² - 2x³s + 4x²rs -2xsr² + x²s²  -2xrs² + r²s² - Q(x)

P(x) =   x⁴ - 2x³r + x²r² - 2x³s + 4x²rs -2xsr² + x²s²  -2xrs² + r²s² - x² - px -q

= x⁴ + x³(-2r-2s) + x²(4rs + r² + s² -1) +x(-2sr² -2rs² - p) + r²s² - q

a = -2r-2s

b=4rs + r² + s² - 1

c = -2sr² - 2rs² -p

d = r²s² - q

you can't find p(x) without the value of p,q,r,s being told